# Action CourseController@publish not defined error while that is defined

Tags: php, laravel

I defined a custom function to a resource controller like this :

```
public function publish (Request $request, $post_id = NULL)
    {
        if (!is_null($post_id)) {
            $result = $this->update($request, $post_id);
        } else {
            $result = $this->store($request);
        }

        if ($result['success']) {
            return ['success' => true, 'msg' => $result['msg']];
        } else {
            return ['success' => false, 'msg' => $result['msg']];
        }
    }
```

And in a blade template I want to link to it like so:

```
$('#publishBtn').click(function () {
   $.post('{{action('CourseController@publish')}}', $('#createCourseForm').serialize() + '&post_status=published', function (data) {
    data.success ? location.href = '/admin/course' : showMsg(data.msg, 'danger');
   });
 });
```

but after opening page error below is shown while really that method exists :

```
    Action App\Http\Controllers\CourseController@publish not defined.   
(View: D:\wamp\www\lms\resources\views\admin\pages\course\course-create.blade.php)
```

Comment: Kindly add your route to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just before `CourseController` Resource route add a route for `publish` method

```
Route::post('publish', [
    'uses' => 'CourseController@publish',
    'as'   => 'publish'
]);

....

Route::resource('course', 'CourseController');
```

Then in your template

```
$('#publishBtn').click(function () {
   $.post('{{route('publish')}}', $('#createCourseForm').serialize() + '&post_status=published', function (data) {
    data.success ? location.href = '/admin/course' : showMsg(data.msg, 'danger');
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a route for that as well.

Comment: define a route is required really? but in the examples and laravel docs (https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#urls), not Referred to.

Comment: @A.B.Developer Yes it's required because Laravel uses the routes defined to determine what path it needs to use to create the URL. Because the URL can't be `CourseController@publish`.

Comment: @user3158900 That's good advice, but an answer consisting of 10 words is better off as a comment. At lease include an example of how to define that route.